# PHP exec cmd doesn't work in my case

Tags: php, windows, cmd, permissions, exec

I've been looking around about 2 days and can't find anything about my problem, I'm trying to run a simple cmd code that works properly if I run it directly from the cmd console. But when I run it from PHP nothing happens, I believe its some kind of permission problem, any ideas?

This is the code I'm trying to run, it execute the html5point_converter.exe that converts my ppt file to html

```
exec("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\HTML5PointSDK\\html5point_converter.exe \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\HTML5PointSDK\\arquivos\\upload1\\teste1.ppt\"");
```

I've tried to execute the following code so that I could test if cmd inside php works, and it is working fine:

```
exec("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c dir", $output);
```

I'm running on windows server 2008 R2, IIS 7 and PHP 5.5 installed with Web Plataform Installer 5.

For test purpose I've set security permission to Full Control to Everyone in:

```
Folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP
Folder: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HTML5PointSDK
File: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HTML5PointSDK\html5point_converter.exe
```

Thanks in advance,
Yours,
Diogo Araujo

Edit 1
I've also tested:

```
exec("C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\HTML5PointSDK\\html5point_converter.exe \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\HTML5PointSDK\\arquivos\\upload1\\teste1.ppt\"");

exec("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c START C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\HTML5PointSDK\\html5point_converter.exe \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\HTML5PointSDK\\arquivos\\upload1\\teste1.ppt\"");
```

Comment: Why do you start `cmd /C`? Why not start the actual program directly?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Golez, I really dont know, i've found this way looking around internet to execute from php, but I tested without it and has no effect, not error msg...

Answer (score 0):

As the highlighter indicates, you have a syntax error in your code. You need to escape the quotes inside the string:

```
exec("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HTML5PointSDK\html5point_converter.exe \"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\HTML5PointSDK\arquivos\upload1\teste1.ppt\", $output);
```

Comment: That is how it is right now

 `exec("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe /c C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\HTML5PointSDK\\html5point_converter.exe \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\HTML5PointSDK\\arquivos\\upload1\\teste1.ppt\"");`
and still doesnt work =\

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but does that command work if you execute it yourself, outside of PHP?

Comment: Okay. Then it is probably some permissions-issue, but for me it's just guessing beyond this point. Since my answer is not current anymore and I don't know how to improve it, I'll delete it shortly. Good luck.